# How to mock static Map property in grails service class unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, dictionary

I have a static map in a service class.I am unit testing the method which populates the map. I want to know how to mock the map used in the service class.

```
SomeService
--------------

class SomeService {
    static Map<Integer,String> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer,String>()
        //This map is used in some other service api
}

OtherService
------------

class OtherService {
    void method1(Integer i, String str) {
        // here it populates the map
        def test = SomeService.tempMap.put(i,str)
        println "After putting : "+test 
    }
}
```

Unit test case

```
OtherServiceTests
------------------
class OtherServiceTests {
    void testMethod1() {
        def mockedMap = mockFor(Map)
        SomeService.metaClass.static.tempMap = mockedMap.createMock()
        SomeService.metaClass.static.tempMap.put = {Integer i, String str -> "Testing"} // how to mock??
    }
}
```

When I run the test case it is invoking the real map instead of making use of the mocked `"put"` api, which is returning null instead of "testing"
I tried couple of ways to mock it but still no luck. How to mock `Map api` which is a `static` property of a service class?

Comment: Grails services are singletons, so you shouldn't store state in them (declare only methods).

Comment: @SérgioMichels Michels I want this map to be accessed from different places. There are multiple put and get operations involved. Will it create a problem if the map is accessed in this way? Service1 will populate map. Service2 will get info from map.Please advise.

Comment: 100% it is going to create a problem. As he said, Services are singleton therfore they maintain state. Whichever globally scoped field is present in service will be available across stateless requests which will lead to erroneous result. It is highly discouraged to add scoped variables in service. You can try with other service scopes which fits to your requirement or drop the idea  of having a static global map in service class altogether.

Comment: @dmahapatro My approach is to create a static map and that should be accessed by all the stateless requests. If the requests contains the correct key then it is allowed to modify the map and that should be visible to all other requests if it access with same key.So in that case what would go wrong?Sorry if I am missing out something.. I am just confused..:(

Comment: but if you run your application as two separate instances and try to load-balance them, then although this would be a static field, it will still be different object in memory - one map per tomcat instance, and it will not contain same data

Comment: If this approach is wrong, can somebody tell me how to achieve the business requirement(like cacheMap in normal application) by not using the static global map inside service class?

Comment: have a look at import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder
import com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mocking you can try

```
SomeService.tempMap.getClass().metaClass.put = {Integer i, String str -> "Testing"}
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm!! I was missing `getClass()`. Thanks for pointing it out.